# dogs barking outside

Tags: phrase-meaning

Can you sense whether "barking outside" is a sing of approval or not? I am not familiar with such kind of English writing.

> JM Rieger tweeted:
> President Biden’s dogs Champ and Major can be heard **barking outside** after Biden signs an executive order lifting a ban on transgender people serving in the military

Comment: JM Rieger does indeed suggest there is either approval or disapproval. But it is up to you to guess which is meant. It is a common device in English writing, but if the reader can't see any significance perhaps the writer has failed. If they were Donald Trump's dogs barking outside the significance would be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you play the video from [the tweet](https://twitter.com/RiegerReport/status/1353761387416219648), you will hear
Biden’s dogs (literally) barking outside. That's what dogs do, they bark. I don't think there is a hidden meaning to this.